# Check proof of Bézout's identity

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

This is my attempt at a proof, which I wonder is correct:

We proof that if $(a,b)=1$ then there exist $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $ax+by=1$.
Consider the set $$S=\{ai\bmod b|i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$
We will prove that $|S|=b$, so that there must be an $i$ such that $ai\equiv1\bmod b$, which completes the proof.

Clearly $ak\equiv a(k+b)\bmod b$ so that $|S|\leq b$. Also, if $|S|<b$ then there must be $0<i<j<b$  s.t. $ai\equiv aj\bmod b$, meaning that $b|a(j-i)$, so since $(a,b)=1$: $b|(j-i)$ but this is not possible since $j-i<b$.

So indeed $|S|=b$.

I just want to be sure this is correct because I haven't done any number theory before this so I'm not quite sure that I did not accidentally make any wrong assumptions/assumptions equivalent to the identity itself or something of that nature.

Comment: "Consider the set... " there seems to be something lost there

Comment: @leonbloy I don't understand what you mean? Don't you see the $S=\{ai\bmod b|i\in\mathbb{Z}\}$?

Comment: There seems to me a problem with `\bmod`. I replaced it (at least temporarily) for '\mod'. Well, forget about it, I rolled back it, it seems to be working now (strange)

Comment: @leonbloy Oke. Can you say anything about the correctness of the proof?

Comment: Yes, by Euclid's Lemma $\,x\mapsto ax\,$ is $1$-$1,\,$ so onto $\,\Bbb Z_b\,$ by the Pigeonhole Principle. See also [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1140067/242) Whether or not the proof is circular depends on whether or not Bezout's Identity was used to prove Euclid's Lemma.